# Did I setup Active Directory on my server correctly? (re: Linux/OSX can't join domain)

Tags: active-directory, windows-domain, windows-server-2012-r2, join

I've just installed Active Directory on my Windows 2012 R2 server and my Windows 8/10 machines connect perfectly, but Linux and OSX can't seem to connect.

The AD server's computer name is "DC01" and I used the following commands to install AD:

> Install-WindowsFeature AD-Domain-Services –IncludeManagementTools
>
> Install-ADDSForest -DomainName "ad.example.com" -DomainNetbiosName "example"  DomainMode Win2008R2 -ForestMode Win2008R2 -InstallDns

If I understand correctly, my active domain FQDN is **ad.example.com**.  The domain is real and registered on the internet, but the subdomain doesn't exist anywhere.  When I enter the domain to join in Windows 8/10, I enter that name and it joins perfectly.  However, when I try any other operating system (OSX, Linux, VMware, etc) it fails.

Does anything look wrong?  I'm using the AD server as my DNS server as well.

I'm getting errors such as:

> KRB5 Error code: -1765328164 (Message: Cannot resolve network address
>   for KDC in realm EXAMPLE.COM)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version(s) of Linux you are using, but I found this article when I was setting up my network:  [How to quickly and easily add a redhat enterprise Linux 6 system to Microsoft Active Directory.](https://www.dalemacartney.com/2012/07/06/how-to-quickly-and-easily-add-a-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6-system-to-microsoft-active-directory/)  This worked for me, pretty much 'as-is'.  How well it works for you depends how similar your setup is.

Some key sticking points:

1. You may need to stage the computer object for the server before you can join the server.
2. Use `net ads` command within Linux to handle admin tasks, especially testing.
3. Remember the `-U *adminaccountname*` switch for `net ads`.  E.g. `net ads join -U DomainAdmin`.

Good luck.  Consider polishing and publishing your results.

Answer (score 0):

The subdomain *does* exist – it's managed by the AD domain controller. That's how clients are supposed to find DCs in the first place. So ideally it should be appropriately delegated from the main domain (using NS records) to the AD DC, for example:

```
ad.example.com. NS dc1.ad.example.com.
dc1.ad.example.com. A 192.0.12.34
```

To start troubleshooting a join, make sure your clients can resolve the following (auto-generated) records from within the AD-managed subdomain:

```
_kerberos._udp.ad.example.com (type SRV)
_ldap._tcp.ad.example.com (type SRV)
```

As another test, you should be able to `kinit Administrator@ad.example.com` even from an unjoined system.

Also try alternative AD clients – aside from the usual Samba (winbind), there's also sssd+realmd.